# How to normalise file path in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The `os.normalized_path` outputs `.` instead of the full path.

```
import os
echo ".".normalized_path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That output is correct - it's "normalised" to the current directory, so it's ".", which is a valid path on *nix. If you want to get the full path, do it like this:

```
import os
echo ".".normalizedPath().absolutePath()
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I formulated the question badly. Updated it, please check it again.

Answer (score 5):

@Yardanico's answer is still the right one, but this got too long to leave as a comment.

`normalizePath` has no knowledge of the current working directory and operates on abstract paths, preserving whether the input is absolute or relative.  what it does is:

- remove extra/trailing slashes: 'foo//bar/' => 'foo/bar'
- resolve double dots: 'foo/../bar' => 'bar', '../foo' => '../foo'
- remove initial './': './foo' => 'foo'

it does not:

- remove initial double dots in absolute paths, i.e. '/..' => '/..'
- convert path delimiters to the native os delimiter.
- handle os9's idiosyncratic updirs properly